# Simple docker application - how to deploy easily?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, cloud

I have a relatively simple web application that consists of two Docker containers working together. One container hosts the web server and the other one hosts a image rendering software.

On my development machine it works flawlessly using `docker-compose`.

For production this application will make use of [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and some database like [Amazon DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/). In that combination the containers itself don't need any persistent storage. Because of those services, my first thought is obviously to use Amazon EC2 to host the application.

My primary goals now are:

- make sure that the application scales *automatically* when the website is under heavy load (requiring a load balancer, of course)
- simple deployment of new container versions without interruption of the service
- set-and-forget kind of solution

At the beginning of the website launch I expect that a single EC2 instance will handle the load easily, with perhaps peaks of two or three EC2 instances during holidays.

Amazon's own Docker hosting solution (with load balancer and auto scaling) looked very promising, but being an Amazon newbie I haven't been able to get this thing working, also because the configuration looks very complex and you have to get the pieces together yourself.

I'm pretty familiar with other types of clusters (mostly Proxmox-based) but still the Amazon Web Services looks complex (at least the configuration console).

Is there any alternative solution that makes this easy?

I spent a lot of time looking into Docker Cloud/Tutum (seems expensive), Docker Swarm, Rancher, and others (most of them "beta"), but still am confused which way to go.

How would you deploy such an application?

Comment: Have you looked at Elastic Beanstalk for hosting your docker web application?

Comment: Didn't know it also supports Docker images and not just a fixed list of programming languages. What's the difference to Amazon EC2 Container Service then? Anyway, I will try to learn more about Beanstalk myself. It looks promising for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already everything working locally, then just look at docker machine. With just a set of API keys from your preferred provider your docker compose will then run on a production deployment: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/

Oreilly just released an ebook on the topic: https://exoscale.ch/docker-in-the-cloud